# Double Integral Regarding Area

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

> If $\int_0^1\int_y^1(x^4+cy^5)\,dx\,dy=1$, what is $c$?

I got 14, but that's the wrong answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The question was copied wrongly onto the paper:
$$\int_y^1(x^4+cy^5)\,dx=[x^5/5+cy^5x]_y^1=1/5+cy^5-y^5/5-cy^6$$
$$\int_0^1(1/5+cy^5-y^5/5-cy^6)\,dy=[y/5+cy^6/6-y^6/30-cy^7/7]_0^1=1/5+c/6-1/30-c/7=1$$
$$6+5c-1-30c/7=30$$
$$5c-30c/7=25$$
$$c-6c/7=c/7=5$$
$$c=35$$